# Prestashop 1.5: category controller not called in ajax

Tags: controller, overriding, prestashop

I'm applying a overriding for category front controller but when I navigate through pages (which is done with ajax) the controller isn't fired at all,

how can I force the controller to be called or what is the correct way to modify output in these cases?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AJAX pagination is done by the blocklayered module and is not using the Category Controller. You will need to override Product::getProductProperties() and at the end of the method to add the additional information at the $row variable.

Comment: Done, and still tje same, controller is not invoked when switching pages, it is invoked when I enter category through a menu entry and shows the first page

Comment: May be the pagination is not using the CategoryController at all and is replacing the content by calling the Category class and rendering the product-list.tpl, pagination.tpl, product-sort.tpl etc. This pagination is done by some 3rd party module, so you may take a look there.